# Adding skype bot to contacts

Tags: skype, botframework, skypedeveloper

Is it possible to add a Skype bot to the contact list without entering the Skype username/password in a browser? Telegram suggests to open an application when we click on the reference. Is there something like that in the Skype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not today but we want to support a similar flow in future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hope it would be soon)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, but only after verifying the bot with the Skype team.
After getting it verified, you can add it by searching in Skype.